# Variable that I'm passing doesn't fetch videos only User Id and profile image (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, firebase

The variable that I'm passing is a user. The user passes but it only displays the username and the profile picture when I pass the uid. When I pass the uid, the username, profile image, AND videos are supposed to pass. I don't know why it's not getting the videos. It only displays the current user (the one that's logged in) videos.

[image: Here's what I mean when I say it only shows current users videos]

[image: Here's the current user that's logged in]

[image: How the database looks]

Here's the code to get a better understanding:

UserSearchController:

```
class UserSearchController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate, GetUserSearchControllerDelegate {

let searchUsersCV: SearchUsersCV = {
    let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    let screenWidth  = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    let cv = SearchUsersCV(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight))
    cv.bringSubview(toFront: cv)
    cv.collectionView.register(UserSearchCVCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellId")

    return cv
}()

func searchControllerDidSelect(passedUser: User) {
    self.searchBar.isHidden = true
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()

    let userProfileController = UserProfileController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())

    userProfileController.userId = passedUser.uid

    (searchUsersCV.next as? UIViewController)?.navigationController?.pushViewController(userProfileController, animated: true)

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(userProfileController, animated: true)
}
```

UserSearchCV:

```
protocol GetUserSearchControllerDelegate {
func searchControllerDidSelect(passedUser: User)
}

class SearchUsersCV: UIView, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,UISearchBarDelegate {

 var delegate: GetUserSearchControllerDelegate?

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    collectionView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
    let user = filteredUsers[indexPath.item]

    delegate?.searchControllerDidSelect(passedUser: user)

}
```

UserProfileController:

```
class UserProfileController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

let cellId = "cellId"
var userId: String?

var user: User?

fileprivate func fetchUser() {
    let uid = userId ?? FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid ?? ""

    FIRDatabase.fetchUserWithUid(uid: uid) { (user) in
        self.user = user

        self.navigationItem.title = self.user?.username

        self.collectionView?.reloadData()

    }        
}
```

If you have any further questions please let me know.

Comment: can I see your database structure and your user class  please

Comment: @iOSGeek yes I have just edited the post!

Comment: @iOSGeek It uploads the posts and receives them properly but it doesn't receive them when viewing other users. It shows the current users posts instead

Comment: Are you iterating and getting details from UID using handler from posts node ? the result you are getting is from node users.

Comment: I don't think so/maybe. I can explain what I mean if we go into a chat room, it'll be better to explain @iOSGeek

Comment: You can do one thing in your user class create two methods that will iterate differently in your post and user node and and when you want to get details of all post including videos call that created method else call other method that only contains user name and image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153509/discussion-between-erik-batista-and-ios-geek).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here I had tried code to get the result as expected . I did this for your userprofileController

1) create two arrays as below

```
var videoUrlArray = [String]()
var thumbnailUrlArray = [String]()
```

2) use the following code don't replace . comment your code and use mine there

```
fileprivate func fetchOrderedPosts() {

    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").child(currentUserID)

    ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "creationDate").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let dict = snapshot.value as! [String:AnyObject]
        print(dict)


        let dictValues = [AnyObject](dict.values)
        print(dictValues)

        for key in dictValues{

            let imageUrl = key["videoUrl"] as! String
            let imageThumbnail = key["thumbnailUrl"] as! String

            self.videoUrlArray.append(imageUrl)
            self.thumbnailUrlArray.append(imageThumbnail)

        }

            self.getResults()
    })
}

func getResults(){

    print("Thumbnail array : \(self.thumbnailUrlArray)")
    print("videoUrlArray : \(self.videoUrlArray)")

     self.collectionView?.reloadData()
}
```

3) output result of console

[image]

now you may need to configure cell according to content that you receive from these two arrays .. Hope it helps :)and let me know If you still face any issue with this code implementation